# How do I patch or modify a list inside of a function when running a unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I think this should have an easy answer and I'm relatively new to Python, so be gentle.

If I have this function:

```
def random_fruit():
    fruits = ['apple','banana','coconut']
    return "I like " + random.choice(fruits)
```

I want to create a test that modifies the fruits list. But I'm can't figure out how to do that.  So I want to do something like this, which obviously does not work.

```
class TestFruit(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('fruits')
    def test_random_fruit(self, fruits_list):
       fruits_list = ['kiwi']
       self.assertEqual(random_fruit(), u"I like kiwi")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this test? I mean, the actual test you are running - I hope its not this

Comment: The purpose was that I was trying to not get a random choice of items. I just wanted to get one back. @jonrsharpe gave a good answer to solve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to test the function would be to [`seed` the `random` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed), rather than try to modify the list, so you get the same "random" result every time:

```
>>> for _ in range(5):
    random.seed(0)
    random_fruit()


'I like coconut'
'I like coconut'
'I like coconut'
'I like coconut'
'I like coconut'
```

Alternatively, make the list an argument (note use of `None` for a mutable default argument - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761)):

```
def random_fruit(fruits=None):
    if fruits is None:
        fruits = ['apple','banana','coconut']
    return "I like " + random.choice(fruits)
```

Which would run like:

```
>>> random_fruit()
'I like coconut'
>>> random_fruit(['kiwi'])
'I like kiwi'
```

Note that there is no point having an argument to `test_random_fruit` if you immediately overwrite it:

```
def test_random_fruit(self, fruits_list):
                          # ^ pass argument
    fruits_list = ['kiwi']
              # ^ overwrite it
    ...
```